# For Loop Over Dictionaries in List (Python 2.7.6)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

For the life of me I cannot figure out why the following is happening:

```
x = 2
y = []
z = { "player" : 0, "name": "none", "fired": 0, "hits": 0, "misses": 0, "streak": 0, "longest streak": 0 }

def number_player(x, y, z):
    for i in range(x):
        y.append(z)
        y[i]["player"] = (i + 1)

number_player(x, y, z)
print y
```

Console returns this:

```
[{'streak': 0, 'hits': 0, 'name': 'none', 'player': 2, 'misses': 0, 'longest streak': 0, 'fired': 0}, {'streak': 0, 'hits': 0, 'name': 'none', 'player': 2, 'misses': 0, 'longest streak': 0, 'fired': 0}]
```

So in short, it creates a key/ value pair of { ..."player" : "2"... } twice. If I request a print at the end of each loop, the first returned dictionary in the list contains a {..."player" : "1"...} key/ value pair as expected.

Stranger to me still is that if I pass:

```
x = 3
y = [{ "player" : 0, "name": "none", "fired": 0, "hits": 0, "misses": 0, "streak": 0, "longest streak": 0 }]
```

then run the for loop so it appends two more dictionaries, the loop operates fine over the first, then duplicates the values of the last two. I assume herein lies the cause and resolve, though I am just too new to this to be able to discern them from the problem.

Your help towards having me understand why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You're filling `y` with **references to the same dictionary**. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your confusion is the line `y.append(z)`.

This does not append a *copy* of the dictionary `z`, but rather another reference to the same instance of `z`.

Therefore, in the last iteration of the loop when you modify the dictionary which you have just appended, you are also modifying the first dictionary which you have appended in the previous iteration.  Your list `y` really just looks like `[z, z]`.

```
>>> print y
[{'streak': 0, 'hits': 0, 'name': 'none', 'player': 2, 'misses': 0, 'longest streak': 0, 'fired': 0}, {'streak': 0, 'hits': 0, 'name': 'none', 'player': 2, 'misses': 0, 'longest streak': 0, 'fired': 0}]
>>> y[0]
{'fired': 0,
 'hits': 0,
 'longest streak': 0,
 'misses': 0,
 'name': 'none',
 'player': 2,
 'streak': 0}
>>> y[0] is y[1]
True
>>> y[0]['player'] = 123
>>> y[1]['player']
123
```

A more pythonic way to create the structure would be with a list comprehension:

```
>>> def new_player(n, name="none"):
...     return {"player" : n, "name": name, "fired": 0, "hits": 0, "misses": 0, "streak": 0, "longest streak": 0}
... 
>>> y = [new_player(n) for n in range(2)]
>>> y
[{'fired': 0,
  'hits': 0,
  'longest streak': 0,
  'misses': 0,
  'name': 'none',
  'player': 0,
  'streak': 0},
 {'fired': 0,
  'hits': 0,
  'longest streak': 0,
  'misses': 0,
  'name': 'none',
  'player': 1,
  'streak': 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, and for the further demonstration of list comprehension. My flaw in logic was thinking that it was indeed simply copying the value of the variable, not copying the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

as others have pointed out you are appending the reference to the same dictionairy

use deepcopy from the copy module.

```
import copy

x = 2
y = []
z = { "player" : 0, "name": "none", "fired": 0, "hits": 0, "misses": 0, "streak": 0, "longest streak": 0 }

def number_player(x, y, z):
    for i in range(x):
        y.append(copy.deepcopy(z))
        y[i]["player"] = (i + 1)

number_player(x, y, z)
print y
```

Comment: Although `copy.deepcopy()` ***is*** needed for the general case, the `dict.copy()` method is adequate here because all the values are simple immutable types - `int`s and `str`s.

Comment: I truly appreciate your answer and the addition of introducing me to the copy module. If my up-votes counted for anything you would have at least one. Thank you.